# Most complete free video codec pack for Windows

Tags: windows, video

I've been using [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/%E2%80%8E) since forever and I'm happy about it. What would be the pros and cons of switching to say K-Lite or VLC? Are there any other codec packs that look promising?

I understand that "best" is kind of broad, but I'd like input on where one excels over the other in say rendering, formats supported, file size, support, etc. Basically, why do you use one and not the other?

Comment: Welcome to  Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Specifically 'Best' isn't really adequate; list what minimum features you need - probably just what minimum formats it needs to support

Comment: What OS? Audio? Video? What price?

Answer (score 4):

VLC is a player with included codecs. You don't need a codec pack if you use VLC.

As a codec pack, I would recommend [K-Lite Mega](http://www.codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_mega.htm). You need it if you use Windows Media Player, or other player that doesn't include codecs. All codecs will be installed system-wide, and will also be used by Windows to generate video thumbnails and specific video details. This pack also contains an useful utlity called MediaInfo. Right-click a media file (audio or video) and select MediaInfo. It will show you codec, stream and other info.

Comment: K-Lite is perfect

Comment: It is also updated frequently.

Comment: Why do people say it's unsafe to install a codec pack? How come they install other non open source players like potplayer(?) which includes codecs as well but they don't mention anything about it being unsafe?

Answer (score 1):

## [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/)

I would recommend sticking with CCCP,
it is great. I have found it to be the most complete.
Prior to using it, I was using multiple different codec packs, combined.
Having to have multiple codec packs can be awkward, they can conflict,
and the more you have to install, the more likely you are to hit one that has something nasty bundled with it.

Along with its completeness,
it is frequently updated.